# Correct way to use HttpClient in .NET 8?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient

I have a .NET 8 app where my app is constantly using `HttpClient` to send requests to a server.  Every time that I think I have a handle on the "correct" way to use `HttpClient`, I start second guessing myself.

First, let's assume that this is a long running app that runs for days at a time collecting data and every few seconds, sends the readings to a server.

Let's also assume that I care about port exhaustion and any DNS issues that may arise.

So, I have created a class called (for this example) `MyHttpClient`.  The reason I am doing this is to be able to pass in typed parameters and auto deserialize the response into that type.  Anyway, that isn't important. But the `MyHttpClient` holds the `HttpClient` object in this example as you can see below.

I add the http client to the `IServiceCollection`.

In my example below, do I need to set the handler lifetime?

Does this example take care of port exhaustion and DNS related issues?  Or, did I completely miss the point here?

Any feedback here would be greatly appreciated....

App.xaml.cs:

```
private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient<MyHttpClient>("MyHttpClient", x =>
    {
        x.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        // allow to connect to self-signed certificate ssl
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) => true;
        return handler;
    });
}
```

`MyHttpClient`:

```
public class MyHttpClient
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;

    public MyHttpClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        _httpClient = client;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetStringAsync(string url, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        try
        {
            _httpClient.Timeout = timeout;

            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default;
            using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url, cancellationToken))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in `SomeService`:

```
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly MyHttpClient httpClient;

    public SomeService(MyHttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<string> TestMe()
    {
        return await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://example.com/api/boblawlaw", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ditch the custom factory. You're overcomplicating it. `SomeService` should depend on `MyHttpClient` directly. `MyHttpClient` doesn't need to be disposable because its dependencies are disposed by the DI container.

Comment: So in my example, if I ditch the factory (I am all about simplifying!), is MyHttpClient then added as a singleton?  Or how does that work?  I just want to be sure I am not creating additional instances when I don't need to?

Comment: No. `MyHttpClient` is registered as Scoped, unless you specify otherwise in `AddHttpClient`. You don't really need to worry about instances of `MyHttpClient` or even `HttpClient`. The thing that gets people in trouble is that doing `new HttpClient()` creates a new handler and that's what causes port exhaustion. The benefit of `IHttpClientFactory` is that it creates and owns the *handler* that's passed to `HttpClient`. It disposes the handler after a certain amount of time and creates a new handler for any new `HttpClient`s that need to be injected.

Comment: It's that activity that prevents port exhaustion. The handler is what owns the connection pool, so it's reusing those for the duration of its lifetime.

Comment: I take it back: `AddHttpClient` has no overloads that take a `ServiceLifetime` and it is, in fact, Transient. That's okay, though, because `HttpClient` instances are just thin wrappers and the handler lifetime is what's important.

Comment: @madreflection _"`MyHttpClient` is registered as Scoped"_ - I believe it is transient by default (for typed clients). [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) _"type specified will be registered in the service collection as a transient service."_

Comment: @GuruStron: Yeah, I corrected myself.

Comment: I just hope that my point about the handler lifetime is still correct.

Comment: Thanks for all of the clarification.  I believe that all makes sense.  I have updated my code above to remove the factory.  Is that looking more like what you were thinking?

Comment: Better. And again, `MyHttpClient` doesn't need to be disposable. The `HttpClient` it gets, and the `HttpMessageHandler` given to the `HttpClient`, are all disposed by the container.

Comment: Some other suggestions for improvements: 1) Add `CancellationToken cancellationToken = default` to the end of the parameters and forward `cancellationToken` to `GetAsync` instead of creating a new `CancellationTokenSource`. 2) `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` is a sledgehammer: brutish and imprecise. You can and should handle error codes more granularly, especially if the endpoint returns meaningful codes, like 400 vs. 404 vs. 409, etc. Your try/catch swallows important exceptions in addition to the "not a success code" exception.

Comment: Swallowing the "important" ones could render your retry policy ineffective.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I will digest everything you said and make more improvements.  :)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the ```.SetHandlerLifetime``` in App.xaml.cs?  Should I not set that at all?  Leave default?  I have read the documentation and still struggle to understand how that all works.

Comment: I would get rid of that. Unless you're facing issues with the default, stick with the default.

Comment: Also, I added the cancellationToken change you suggested above.  That makes sense, but don't I need to somehow specify a timeout for the cancellationToken?  Or do I not need to do that?

Comment: You shouldn’t dispose what you don’t directly create

Comment: That's another thing you don't need to do unless you're having issues with it.

Comment: As a side note, I may have misunderstood your retry policy, but waiting and retrying on a 404 seems pointless. If you're waiting for some other process to create whatever resource it didn't find, that shouldn't be a policy applied to the whole typed client.

Comment: This may be a use case for the 202 Accepted response. Either the response provides an endpoint you can poll until it indicates that the resource is ready, or the endpoint returning it can accept a callback endpoint that it can request when the resource is ready.

Comment: Perhaps a 404 isn't the correct thing to be looking for when creating the retry policy. It is rare, but sometimes that requests don't go through, so if it wasn't successful, I wanted to try it a couple of times?  Perhaps there is a better way to do that though?

Comment: I think I am going to just remove the retry policy for now and see if it becomes an issue.  I have modified the code and it looks lot simpler now.  And yeah, I agree about error handling.  I will get around to that part eventually.  :)

Comment: I think that's prudent. It's important to understand that if you're getting a 404, *it went through*.

Comment: See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-JGay_lnWI